# Is it possible to terminate the hangout from a hangout app

Tags: google-plus

I would like to write a hangouts app that guarantees the hangout will end at a given time. This will keep meeting from running over time.

It would be sufficient to disconnect users from the current hangout. My alternative approach will be to create a browser extension that just closes the tab.

Is there anyway to accomplish this with the hangouts API? I didn't see anything on a cursory scan through the docs.

Comment: What do you mean a hangout app?  Is that a third-party app that runs on Google Hangout environment?

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no specific "quit hangout" or "close hangout" function, if everyone is running the same hangout app, then something could trigger them all to leave the hangout at (or near) the same time or on command. Since hangout apps are just javascript that runs inside the browser, they could all execute something like

```
location.href = 'http://example.com/hangout-is-over.html';
```

What causes them all to execute this, where they go, how to get them all to run the app in the first place, and anything else along those lines is something you'll have to solve in the context of your business logic, however.